# How does one use the SEAESRT charging hazard graphic that NOAA provides?

Tags: spacecraft-charging, noaa

[NOAA provides a dashboard for satellite operators](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/seaesrt). One of the tiles provided is the Charging Hazard graphic included below:
[image: SEAESRT Charging Hazard]

I'm not quite sure how is this infographic used?

How do satellite operators use this image? What does the red between 0-30 deg E & 0-30 deg N mean? What does the blue between 40S - 80S mean?

Comment: What is the source of the image?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "What does the blue between 40S - 80S mean?" Oceans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how they use the data (though [this handbook](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA262778.pdf) might have some interesting reading, but I can answer the latter half.

From the [link you posted](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/seaesrt):

> The Spacecraft Environmental Anomalies Expert System – Real Time (SEAESRT) is a set of data-driven algorithms that indicate the likelihood of an environment-related anomaly on a geosynchronous satellite.

Since this is focused on satellites in geosynchronous orbits, they are mainly centered around the equator, which is why the coverage of the map only centers there. Therefore, the blue between 40S and 80S would just be the normal map without overlay, and that's just the ocean.

The green/yellow/red would be indicators of the level of hazard for a satellite in an orbit over that area. The specific graphic you posted is less than fully clear, but it seems to be a snapshot-in-time of the hazard in the area, while other graphics they provide include more danger-over-time focused information.[image: other graphic from the same NOAA site depicting Surface Charging, Internal Charging, Total Dose, and Single Event Effects in a time series]

Based on the coloration in the Surface Charging section of this plot matching the colors in the original graphic you're asking about, I would *guess* that the yellow is a greater than 92% chance of the level of charge posing a hazard while red is greater than 97% chance to pose a hazard, assuming I'm interpreting the latter correctly.

Answer (score -2):

The image shows the spacecraft surface charging alarm levels in green / yelow / red colors. The green means no risk, the yellow means potential hazards of surface charging may occur on GEO orbit (indicated slot region - 270 East or 90 West)

-> 40 S - 80 S blue areas indicate the oceans over the projected map of the Earth.

Comment: Ref: SEAES-GEO: A spacecraft environmental anomalies expert system for geosynchronous orbit https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2009SW000473

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what do you think this answer adds beyond the existing answer?  I think you're actually entirely wrong about green meaning "no risk" per both the other answer and paragraph 34 / table 3 of the paper you cited.

Comment: Green color means the predicted result for surface charging will be below 92nd percentile in GEO orbit (score will be equal or less than 2.5). In quiet conditions, the prediction will be less than 0.5. Moderate substorm conditions (Kp =< 6) this parameter will be high (yellow + red). Current spacecraft tech. reside in the GEO will be affected. Satellites in eclipse season (March to May and August to October) could be affected and charged up to minus tens of kV's of differential surface charging; however, under sunlight conditions, the surface charge will be limited by photo-emission phenomena.

Comment: The surface charging (red and yellow colors in the figure above); from 0 to 6 AM  local time in the Magnetosphere - Earth frame. The magnetic local time from 0 to 6 MLT, is dangerous in substorm conditions, which is indicated by another chart in the prediction page for surface charging.